# Expo EAS build error Cannot find module '@expo/config-plugins'

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build android production application using Expo EAS but it is throwing error.

Expo SDK: 49
Command: `eas build -p android --profile production`
package.json file have this `"@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2"`

```
Build failed
Cannot find module 'expo/config-plugins'
Require stack:
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-build-properties/build/android.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-build-properties/build/withBuildProperties.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-build-properties/app.plugin.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withStaticPlugin.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withPlugins.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/index.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/android/expoUpdates.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/utils/expoUpdates.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/android.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/index.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/index.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/src/services/worker/dist/service.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/src/services/worker/dist/ws.js
- /usr/local/eas-build-worker/src/services/worker/dist/main.js
```

I have tried with node version 16, then I upgraded to version 18. I have tried upgrading expo-cli.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding

```
...
"overrides": {
  "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2"
}
```

to your `package.json` file

Comment: @rajatBhardwaj did this help ?